# Fading on additional materials to a section of an object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, keyframes

I have a texture mapped material with additional bump maps, etc.  It looks fine.  I have created a shape animation where one end of the object becomes cratered (concave).  Inside the crater the material needs to gradually change to another color.  I have assigned the vertex group (inside of crater) the new material, but I can't figure out how to 'fade' it in while the object changes shape.  This is using cycles.

[image: RoughCraterTest]

I'd upload the file but the client is sensitive about his IP.

Thanks for anyone's time

Answer (score 1):

To fade from one colour to another you add keyframes to the factor of a mix node.

[image]

You can also get more control by using an animation to control which colour is used. [Dynamic paint](http://www.blender.org/manual/physics/dynamic_paint/index.html) could be used to create the image sequence.

[image]

Comment: My particular issue is that I need to bring the 2nd material in over the texture map, not another similar material.  In an old version of Blender Internal render I think I could add one material on top of another.  This probably wasn't an intended procedure, but it was possible.  I think I may ultimately create a 2nd layer of geometry, which with it's separate color will give me all the control  I need.

Comment: Say red is the normal surface material, blue is the second material you want mixed in. An image that when fed into the diffuse colour would make the object white would make the object show as blue if it was fed into the mix factor, a black image would make it red, by having it 50% grey you get a 50% mix of both. By animating the transition you define which part of the model shows which material on what frame.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mixing between 2 materials, I painted a 2nd texture map with a soft edged alpha channel.  The object using the 2nd map was cut from a duplicate of the crater area (without shape key effects).  I'll call this 'crater overlay'.  The overlay was then shrinkwrapped (+ solidify modifier) over the crater and on to the original asteroid object. Shrinkwrap works just fine with the target objects shape keys.  On the original asteroid I also painted an additional texture map for 'mixing' in darker burn marks around the rim.  JA12 over at Blenderartists.org has a nice procedural method, but I cannot understand it well enough to apply to my model - better off just painting for now.  Below is my result.

[image]